# @Value from application.yml returns wrong value

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

In my `application.yml` file there is declared:

```
service:
  a: 
    b: 011600
    c: 011200
```

selecting value from `.yml` via `@Value` annotation:

```
@Value("${service.a.c}")
private String VALUE;
```

Instead of expected '011200' I am getting '4992', which isn't mentioned in .yml.

Comment: Did you try to quote the numbers? Starting with 0 it's like it will be interpreted like octal or hexadecimal numbers ... just guessing

Comment: @alphamikevictor, yeah, really, quotes worked. thank you for your comment, seems that it's correct answer

Comment: But 4992 isn't hex/oct representation

Comment: I know, I was trying to convert, and didn't find which kind of conversion was performing; but you get the idea some conversion was done if not quoted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not specify which version YAML your document has, and it looks like your parser defaults to version 1.1 (or version 1.1 compatibility). This causes values starting with 0 followed by digits to be interpreted as octal, and value of `011200` (octal) is `4736` (decimal), the value of `011600` (octal) is `4992`.

In YAML 1.2, octal integer values should start with `Oo` and therefore `011200` will be the integer `11200`

Try using:

```
%YAML 1.2
---
service:
  a:
    b: 011600
    c: 011200
```

and if that doesn't get you the value you want, you should consider using a compliant YAML parser (the YAML 1.2 specification is from 2009, so there has been ample time to get things right).

You can of course quote your integer scalars, but then they will be loaded as strings, not as integers. In that case you don't need to specify the version tag, both version 1.2 and 1.1 interpreted that the same way:

```
service:
  a:
    b: '011600'
    c: '011200'
```

If after getting the decimal values you specified in the file, you still get the wrong value for `@Value("${service.a.c}")` then, you should consider using a different access method (something that works if there is a dot in the key (e.g. `serv.ice:`) or, again, a different parser.

Comment: The yaml engine used by spring boot does not support yaml 1.2 (yet). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56558270/does-spring-boot-2-1-x-support-yaml-1-2-specification

Answer (score 2):

Just try to quote your values, so they are strings.