# Does spring boot 2.1.x support yaml 1.2 specification

Tags: spring-boot, yaml, snakeyaml

Does spring boot 2.1.x support yaml 1.2 specification?

If not, is it possible to use yaml 1.2 + snakeyaml-engine for the spring boot  application.yml support?

Comment: I have not found an explicit reference to the version number, but since they use the extension `.yml` in their [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and that the [officially recommended extension](https://web.archive.org/web/20060924190202/http://yaml.org/faq.html) has been `.yaml` since 2006, it is not very likely they support the YAML 1.2 spec from 2009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot uses snakeyaml 1.23.

From the description this is YAML 1.1

```
<description>YAML 1.1 parser and emitter for Java</description>
```

Because YAML is supported by snakeyaml-engine and not in snakeyaml the API is not compatible so you will not be able to use it in Spring Boot

Comment: It would be good for them to put that in the documentation. So people don't use any incompatible features of YAML 1.2, as recently introduced as ten years ago.

Comment: The Spring Boot Reference Documentation shows that it uses SnakeYaml and SnakeYaml says it supports 1.1. But I don't know the reason why thy don't use YAML 1.2. You should ask the Spring Boot team

Comment: spring boot 2.x uses version 1.19 https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.0.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/pom.xml

Comment: @Paizo Spring Boot 2.0.x uses 1.19 Spring Boot 2.1.x uses 1.23